# Pentaho PDI how to validate source Excel metadata for the order and number of columns?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

In my case, I need to process input data in Excel (xls and xlsx) format. I need to do a file level validation of the Excel file for the order and number of columns, before processing the row level data. If this file level validation is failed, then exclude this file and inform the concerned through mail.

Please guide me, with some sample or example, how to validate the excel files for metadata? I thought of placing a variable in kettle.properties with semicolon separated  header fields and compare this with the source excel file. But not getting a way to extract only the header row from file as I want.

Please guide me.

Comment: if you are using excel file input step then at the time clicking on get sheetname(s) under sheets and get fields from header row under fields it is giving error pop-up if the file is not of xls or xlsx extension, so it itself validating file before any other process..
you want any other thing ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The use case is, hundreds of source Excel files will be kept in FTP. There are chances that few of the excel files may not be in the agreed format and we need have file level validation to exclude them and inform data owner (customer) to correct it.

Comment: I am not aware with how you can do this, wait for someone else to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Are column names on Row 1 of your file (or any other row reasonably close to row 1) and you know how many fields are in each, at most? If so, maybe you can get away with that.

Step 1: You need to understand how many rows may there be, what they may be called, what data types, etc.

Step 2: Read the first N rows of the file(s) ensuring the header row will be read; Filter everything that is not the header (how to? depends on the specific structure). Because you don't know what are the field names, just name them field0, ... field999 or whatever.

Step3: Work some magic on the headers; filtering based on position of certain fields, mapping field names to data types, etc.

Step4: Metadata injection. Using the information you already have from before, you create a template transformation that is generic in the sense that field names are not set up in the excel input step. The metadata injection allows you to set up that step in run time, depending on the entire logic you just applied on the headers.

This page has a couple example videos: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/ETL+Metadata+Injection

I had to build something like that (only it was CSV files and not XLS) a while back and metadata injection allowed me to load every single file in one go with 100% mapping accuracy. Of course, the magic happens before, when you parse the header row.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks nsousa for your answer.

I got to the required solution with the help of my colleague. Here what I did

(1) Read only the 1st row of the source Excel file as normal data (no header, limit 1) where the field names will be called as F1, F2 etc

(2) concat the fields (data) to get a pattern

(3) Match this pattern with acual metadata pattern, if they are matching, then excel file is passed

Good trick. Thanks.